# Question posted an hour *after* the *most recent visit* by the OP

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183251/select-from-clause) question was created 1 hour ago:

[image]

However, the user's [profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99868/francesco-mantovani) shows the "last visit" by the user was *2* hours ago:

[image]

Comment: One rounding up, the other rounding down? Maybe.

Answer (score 8):

The profile page is heavily cached, and doesn't update as quickly as the question page.

You can blame caching or **magic**, but I'd go with caching.

Comment: I suppose caching doesn't apply when I view my own profile page?  It seems to update quite rapidly.

Comment: @MaxVernon It is very cached for example, I was poking around the site a minute ago, but I just went to my profile page and it says I was last seen 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I tend to blame magic.